# How to remove 2 containers using the .remove() EXTJS

Tags: extjs

I want to remove container items in a row. I'm using the `.remove()` of 'EXTJS' for removal. However I'm unable to remove both the containers at a time.

**I did this:** `this.remove(filter, test);` and it does not work. Any ideas how to remove both the containers using the `remove()`.

**Below is the code:**

```
somefunc: function (token, filter, op) {
    var test = Ext.create({
        xtype: 'container',
        height: 30,
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox',
            align: 'middle'
        },
        text: "AND"
    });
    var filter = Ext.create({
        xtype: 'container',
        height: 30,
        cls: 'purge-filter-item',
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox',
            align: 'middle'
        },
        items: [
            this.typeCombo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
                emptyText: $L('Select a filter...'),
                store: this.menuStore = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                    fields: ['key', 'title'],
                    data: this.getFilterValues()
                })
            })
        ]
    });
    this.remove(filter, test);

    this.doLayout();
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it's problematic to call remove twice?

Comment: `remove` can remove only one component i think, You have to call it twice

Comment: that worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.remove([filter, test]);
```

Use an array containing the objects you want to remove.

If you need to destroy them you can use the remove second param like this:

```
this.remove([filter, test],true);
```